# How do you populate a .net drop down list using MDX?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, ssas, mdx

I'm looking to build a web application using an SSAS cube as the data platform.

As such, I would like to list the dimensions in drop down lists. For example, I have a dimension called Dim Company.

How do I populate the drop down list with these individual companies?

Any examples or pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Skip the cube if you can. Pull directly from the warehouse. Cubes are heavy expensive animals, difficult to work with at best.

Answer (score 0):

ADOMD allows you to query the cube's structure as well as the data. You don't need any MDX; you can get it to list the dimensions on a certain cube, or list the members in a certain level of a certain dimension. Here's a very old ASP example:

```
Set oCat = Server.CreateObject("ADOMD.Catalog")
Set oCat.ActiveConnection = oCon
Set oDim = oCat.CubeDefs("CubeName").Dimensions("DimName")
Set oMembers = oDim.Hierarchies(0).Levels(2).Members
'then loop oMembers and get their .Caption property
```

If you do know MDX, you can write a query to list the members you want, without returning any data, and just use part of the results to populate the dropdown. For example:

```
SELECT {[Location].[All Location].children} ON ROWS, 
{} ON COUMNS 
FROM [CubeName]
```

You could even issue this from SQL using `OPENROWSET` if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at CellSetGrid source code.

CellSetGrid is an Open Source ASP .Net (c#) control, which offers pivot table like functionality for SSAS Cubes.

[This used to be available for download in this site:
www.SQLServerAnalysisServices.com
Now the site does not host this control anymore]

So I have uploaded the source of the control - CellSetGrid here.

http://www.box.net/shared/6gi0n79q6t